# How can I use an async function to await for an onClick() event (Choice between 2 Buttons in a Modal)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, onclick, return

Some context: I need an async await function or Promise/Resolve to return the button of choice a user selects. The reason I need it this way is because I'm calling a deletePost function from within a specific child Post component and I need a Modal that exists at a parent component level to prompt the user to confirm a Delete or Cancel. I then need that decision to be returned to the child Post component to continue on with the deletion process or cancel it depending on what button the user clicks in the Modal.

The reason it has to be this way is because all the data for the post I want to delete exists at that child Post component level so the entire functionality for deletion of a post needs to be at the Post component level and I'm looking to link that to a Modal at a higher parent level which will allow me to confirm of cancel that deletion process at the click of a button on the modal

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Example = async () => {
  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleModal = async () => {
    // Opens Modal
    setModalOpen(!modalOpen);

    let decision = null;  // should be "delete" or "cancel" for return

    /*
        This toggleModal() function will be called from within a child 
        component's deletePost() function to prompt a user for confirmation 
        of deletion or cancellation. Once the modal opens up, I believe I 
        need some kind of async await function HERE to wait on a click 
        decision from the user and then return that selected value all the 
        way back to the deletePost() function that was called from within 
        the child Post component.
    */

    return decision;
  };

  const modalStyle = {
    display: modalOpen ? "block" : "hidden",
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={toggleModal}>Open Modal</button>
      <Modal style={modalStyle}>
        
        {/* How to link these buttons to the async await function above */}
        <button>Delete</button>
        <button>Cancel</button>
      </Modal>
      {posts.map((post, index) => (
          <Post
            key={post.id}
            post={post}
            toggleModal={toggleModal}
          />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Example;
```

Comment: Your buttons are labelled _Delete_ and _Cancel_, not _Confirm_ and _Cancel_ as per your comment.  That's a tiny bit distracting to me.

Answer (score 1):

I just published a package to handle your case.

Installation:

```
npm install use-awaitable-component
```

Usage:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import useAwaitableComponent from "use-awaitable-component";

const Example = async () => {
  const [awaitModalStatus, awaitModalExec, awaitModalResolve, awaitModalReject, awaitModalReset] = useAwaitableComponent();
  const modalOpen = awaitModalStatus === 'awaiting' // Show modal while awaiting

  const awaitModal = async () => {
    try {
      const decission = await awaitModalExec();
      console.log(decission);
    } finally {
      awaitModalReset()
    }
  };

  const modalStyle = {
    display: modalOpen ? "block" : "hidden",
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={awaitModal}>Open Modal</button>
      <Modal style={modalStyle}>
        <button onClick={() => awaitModalResolve('delete')}>Delete</button>
        <button onClick={() => awaitModalReset()}>Cancel</button>
      </Modal>
      {posts.map((post, index) => (
        <Post
          key={post.id}
          post={post}
          toggleModal={awaitModal}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Example;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your exact use case, but if you want to know whether user selected `Cancel` or `Confirm`, you can do that with attaching separate `onClick` event on those two buttons.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Example = async () => {
  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleModal = () => {
    // Opens Modal
    setModalOpen(!modalOpen);
  };
 
  const handleConfirm = () => { //confirm logic }
  const handleCancel = () => { //cancel logic }



  const modalStyle = {
    display: modalOpen ? "block" : "hidden",
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={toggleModal}>Open Modal</button>
      <Modal style={modalStyle}>
        <button onClick={handleConfirm}>Confirm</button>
        <button onClick={handleCancel}>Cancel</button>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Example;
```

This way you keep all the methods separate and don't even need to use async await, i.e. use for user to either click one of those buttons.

Edit: Added this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modaldeleteconfirm-es5re) based on my understanding of op's comment.

Comment: No this isn't what I'm looking for. Let me explain. I need an async await function to return a value containing the button of choice the user selected. The reason I need it this way is becuase I'm calling this function from another component in order to confirm the deletion of a post. So the decision to go forward with that API call to delete the post needs to be confirmed through the modal and I need to wait on the user's decision

Comment: Still I don't get why you need to wait on the users choice. Even if you are calling the modal component from another component and has the delete logic in the calling component, you can still use this approach of binding the buttons to a callback function and then proceed based on user input, rather than awaiting for user input. 
I've added a codesandbox link in the answer, if I understood correctly that's what you want. Let me know if its otherwise.

Also, I am not sure if something like that exists or how complex that is with React.

Comment: Hey I've updated the question and the code to be very specific. Please also read the comment within the code to fully understand

Comment: Is your modal component (containing the delete and cancel buttons) always visible or depends on modal state? Also, couldn't find any reference to deletePost method which is referred in the code comment : "then return that selected value all the 
        way back to the deletePost() function that was called from within 
        the child Post component."

Comment: If possible, can you create a sandbox with the necessary components and all?